# Images have a fubar color palette when generated under Xvfb instead of normal X

Tags: linux, image-processing, x11, wolfram-mathematica, vnc

When generating a png image file in Mathematica on a linux box running X, there's no problem.  Doing the same on a linux machine without X but instead Xvfb the png generates fine but the colors are all screwed up.  We tried changing the pixel depth from the default of 8, to no avail.  Any other tweaks that might make Xvfb mimic normal X better, or is this more likely a Mathematica bug?

I actually suspect this has nothing to do with Mathematica.  I'm finding other accounts on the web of people having trouble generating reasonable quality jpegs in OpenOffice under Xvfb.  I've seen recommendations to use VNC instead of Xvfb.  Is that likely to solve this problem?

Here's how the image looks when generated on the machine with X11:

http://yootles.com/outbox/dmass-x.png

And here's how it looks generated on the machine with Xvfb:

http://yootles.com/outbox/dmass-xvfb.png

Comment: Looks like using VNC as a virtual X server instead of Xvfb will solve this, but it seems to be quite slow...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with a pixel depth of 24?

Comment: Have not tried that; the urgency went away after getting it to work with VNC.  I'd still like to get to the bottom of this though.  Do you have a theory as to why it might work with 24 when it didn't with 32?

Comment: Well, I missed the part you said you tried 32bit.  Your pix match where the application can't get it's colors in 8bit mode.
The default in simulation mode is 24bit.

Comment: I also am experiencing this problem and it is not so easy to use VNC instead (I am running this on a cluster and I would have to get that admins to install VNC for me) so it would be nice to understand why xvfb produces such crappy results. I tried 24bit and it didn't look any different to 32bit.